# creating an IBM bluemix app using softlayer object storage in java .I have softlayer account already

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

creating an IBM bluemix app using softlayer object storage in java .I have softlayer account already. Dont want to use Watson Object storage rather want to use existing softlayer object store account please help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user-provided service with your existing SoftLayer account info. This will add it to the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable, then use it in your app like any other Bluemix service.

```
cf cups SERVICE_INSTANCE -p '{"username":"admin","password":"pa55woRD"}'
```